# JavaFX - Rotating On The Spot?

Tags: object, javafx, rotation, pivot, shapes

I have created a method that allows me to select a shape and rotate it. I was wondering if anyone knows how to rotate it 45 degrees on the spot.

**RotateMethod**

```
public void rotateObject() {
    int i=0;
    selectedShapes.get(i++).getTransforms().add(new Rotate(45, 360, 360));
}
```

The method gets the selected item and then rotates it when a button is clicked. Currently it will rotate it 360 degrees around the scene. I want it to rotate around the same spot. If there is a better way of implementing this rotate method please enlighten me.  Thank You

**EDIT:**

After implementing the method stated below, the selected shape now rotates 45 degrees as required. However, it only rotates once, how can I re-write the method to allow it to rotate 45 degrees every time I click on my rotate button

```
public void rotateObject(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    int i = 0;
    selectedShapes.get(i++).setRotate(45);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it will rotate it 20 degrees on x,y 360,360. I think this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
double angle[0] = {0};

public void rotateObject(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    int i = 0;//I don't understand this part of our code?
    angle[0] = angle[0] + 45;//Every time the button is pressed rotate 45 degrees.
    selectedShapes.get(i++).setRotate(angle[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hey, this does what I want it to! so thank you for that! however I can only rotate it once. Do you know how I would write it so that it would keep rotating it (every time I click a button). Thanks

Comment: Hey, I tried it still no luck. The int i  is a way of accessing the elements within the node.                                                                                   private List<Node> selectedShapes = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Yea but the way it is written you are always calling the element when i = 0;

Comment: I guess this is where the problem lies hmm..      The method in my inital question seemed to work fine, but would not rotate on the spot

Comment: Same annoying issue. Rotates 45 degrees and then the button stops working. :/ So damn annoying

Comment: I am guessing that you put double angle[0] = {0} inside your rotateObject() method. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Such a rookie mistake! Thanks Man. Saved me